# How does MIPS ( or any other multi-byte word arch ) fetch a word?

Tags: computer-architecture

I've recently been studying MIPS as part of a CS course, but something bugs me.
We've seen so far that MIPS increments the PC by 4 each cycle because each word is in fact comprised of 4 bytes (32 bits), each with their own address. 
I've also seen that a theoretical RISC machine has instructions that should only take a single cycle to execute.

Ignoring memory latency, how does it manage to generate an address for each 4 bytes? 
It can't have four adders for memory address calculation right? That'd be too expensive! Or am I incorrect in this assumption? 
I've also seen other architectures that manage to pull multiple bytes from memory (even multiple words) in a single step/cycle/instruction, but how is this achieved if each byte needs an address?

Comment: I don't know the details of MIPS but I don't really understand your question. First, why would four adders working in parallel be a problem? Second, why would you need them? Isn't the fetch instruction essentially "Get me the four bytes beginning at this address"? Why does that require computing four addresses?

Comment: Imagine the following: You have the program counter at X, and would like to read four bytes. So you read the first byte at X, increment (to X+1) read that byte, increment (X+2), read that byte, increment (X+3) and read that byte and increment to X+4. Now the PC is incremented by four and you've read the next word of memory. Reading four NON-CONTIGUOUS bytes requires knowing four addresses, however reading the next four bytes in memory only requires one address (and knowing how many times to increment).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I was under the impression that you absolutely need to be able to provide the 4 addresses in one step . JustAnotherSoul 's comment makes me realize that incrementing the PC 3 times in one clock cycle is also a possibility.  Is a full adder required for incrementing the PC, or can a smaller circuit be designed assuming you only ever increment by 1 ?

Comment: For all we know, memory is word-addressed, so the CPU sends to the memory controller the address of the first byte, and gets all 4 bytes in return.

Comment: It seems that the exact answer to this question depends on knowledge of the MIPS architecture, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It's not really MIPS specific. The question is just about reading words of memory on byte-addressed architectures which, due to some misunderstanding, the asker seems to believe to be impossible.

Comment: Okay . How is it implemented then ? I'm sorry if i'm being thick here , but how does one design circuitry that pumps out multiple bytes at once?

Comment: @coaxialgamer There is nothing fundamental about a byte. If you're happy to accept that circuitry exists to pull 8 bits out of the memory, then you should accept that circuitry exists to pull 9 bits, 10 bits, 18 bits, 27 bits, 32 bits, 34 bits or any other number. It's no different. You have a fundamental misunderstanding. You appear to believe that a memory is a device that you give an address to and it returns an 8-bit byte, and that anything else (such as returning a 32-bit word) requires special explanation. It doesn't. It's the same thing, only with different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

MIPS can load a 32-bit (4-byte) word in a single instruction (load word, `LW`). The fact that each byte of the word is individually addressable doesn't affect this.  Effectively, the instruction says "Read the four bytes beginning at this address", not "Read the byte at this address.  Increment the address by one.  Read the byte at that address.  Increment the address by one.  Read the byte at that address.  Increment the address by one.  Read the byte at that address."

By way of an analogy, you can photocopy any two facing pages of a book simultaneously, even though each has its own number.

Comment: And can someone explain to a theoretician like me why one would want bytes to be addressable? Why not just have addressable words?

Comment: @AndrejBauer As a fellow theoretician, I would guess it's because MIPS was designed in the 1980s, when memory was small and expensive. Many quantities (e.g., a character of text, back in the days before Unicode) fit in a single byte of memory and it would have seemed ridiculously profligate to use a 32-bit word to store an 8-bit value, and ridiculously inefficient to have to use multiple instructions to retrieve a whole word from memory and then shift and mask to obtain the desired byte.

Comment: A theoretician might point out that at most 24 bits will be wasted on any string, not three times as many bits. Anyhow, yes those sound like plausible reasons. We're stuck with design decisions that made sense in the past. Programming languages are full of them.

Comment: @AndrejBauer See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53936/why-is-word-addressable-the-exception-not-the-rule/53942#53942

Comment: @AndrejBauer Ah but, even though you'd only waste 1-3 bytes per string, as a programmer it's much easier to loop through a string by incrementing a byte pointer than by incrementing a word-pointer and then decoding the individual characters from those words. Nowadays, one might expect one's optimizing compiler to convert the former to the latter anyway to decrease memory accesses, but I doubt a 1980s compiler would be that sophisticated.

Comment: Here's what i don't get. How is that done? As far as I've learned anyway, be it for SRAM or auto refresh DRAM ;you provide a byte address, swing the output_enable (and appropriate) pin to high, which gets you the data contained at the address during the rising or falling edge. I didn't know about any mechanism allowing you to ask for a byte, and then get x bytes after that in return. Is that actually possible?

Comment: @coaxialgamer There is an instruction that says "load the word at address X into register Y". It's done by having circuitry that does that. You seem to believe that, since every byte has an address, it's somehow only possible to read memory a byte at a time. That's simply not true. It's like believing that, because every person has a name, you can only talk to one person at a time.

Comment: @coaxialgamer If we're talking about "normal" memory, most modern CPUs work on cache lines internally, which are typically 32, 64, or 128 bytes in size. Blocks of that size are transferred between the CPU and RAM (or the CPU and lower-level cache). If the CPU wants to perform a load, internal circuitry in the CPU extracts word or byte-sized blocks from the appropriate cache line. It's a similar story for memory stores, where the result is written directly into the cache line.

Comment: Oh, the typical example of a memory operation that isn't "normal" is when the address is actually a hardware device. Memory-mapped I/O register accesses are typically uncached. Large blocks of memory owned by devices (e.g. video frame buffers) have their own complex issues.

Comment: @Pseudonym Caches, memory-mapped IO and anything else is massively over-complicating things for this question. The asker's difficulty appears to be that they believe that a memory can, for some fundamental reason, only return an 8-bit byte and that returning anything else (e.g., a 32-bit word) requires some special explanation, such as retrieving four bytes sequentially.

Comment: I respectfully disagree on caches. The unit of transfer between RAM and a modern CPU is the cache line. Words and bytes are implemented as operations on cache lines.

Comment: @Pseudonym The asker doesn't understand the basics. Please don't confuse them more by introducing more advanced topics. Of course caches are important. But somebody who can't grasp the idea of reading 32 bits from memory isn't going to be helped by you saying, "Actually, it doesn't come from the memory at all -- it comes from the cache!"

Comment: @David Richerby I have studied caches, and have a basic understanding of how they function. I mainly took a high level view of memory until now, which is why i never asked myself the above question. Thinking about it, it would be possible to chain multiple memory devices and synchronize the addresses of all those chips, effectively allowing me to pull 16/32/64 bits in one operation. Problem is that doing so would only require incrementing PC+1 at every cycle, not pc+4, which is why I've been confused.

Comment: @coaxialgamer You still seem to be thinking in terms of memories being devices that take one address and return one byte. They aren't. You don't need these four parallel memories; you just need circuitry to read 32 bits at once.

Answer (score -4):

the cpu might have used an integrated circuit to clone one single instruction command to a number that the same number of instruction set executive commands,how for it will always be executed by transistors logic gate.Your question is unclear,i assume the command is a 8 bits so this 8 bits will be parsed and the output will have to be **11111111** and if not,it will be:
example: **10110010** so if the command is available,it will switch circuit to address 8th to send to a i/o another processing circuit to send the next commands to ram or peripheral devices.if not,it will switch to address 4th.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you're trying to say, here. Also, MIPS instructions are 32 bits long (which is why the PC is incremented by 4 bytes).

Comment: Maybe you could use more capitals and punctuations, it helps a lot to understand a post. Furthermore, if somebody says, "I don't understand X", it is very nice (and, from the view of the upvotes, very useful), if you take the advice and edit the post accordingly. For everybody getting the effort of commenting your post, there are a *lot* of others who didn't (and, some of them, may downvote the post).